# tests fail or hang randomly on travis with PhantomJS

Tags: javascript, ember.js, phantomjs, travis-ci, testem

I run my tests with testem and PhantomJS, they all pass on my local machine, but when i run them on travis, they fail randomly, or hang, It's not like some specific tests fail, some pass, randomsome fail, I have no idea what's going on. My project is available on github https://github.com/eguneys/marbles-site

**Edit**:

I've optimized it a little, it fixed the hang issue, now the problem is it fails the first integration test. I added an `App.reset()` before the first integration test. And it passes now. I had trouble with `App.reset()` before,

Erik Bryn suggested that you can use `App.reset()`  in the `setup` method rather than `teardown` so you can see the application's last state. But that causes tests to fail, i can't solve the mystery of `App.reset()` and fear the tests will fail anytime now. Yet they pass at the moment.

Comment: Which of your tests fail? Your integration tests or your unit tests?

Comment: @yorbro hm, it's random really, sometimes unit tests fail, sometimes integration tests hangs, i use ember-test-helpers with qunit. here's a [log](https://travis-ci.org/eguneys/marbles-site/builds/33861034)

Comment: Since the tests do pass I'm thinking it's related to either PhantomJS or Gulp? Unfortunately, I do not enough about them to be able to help you...

Answer (score -1):

Go to your package.json file and change scripts.test like this:

```
"test": "testem ci --launch node,PhantomJS"
```

I'm not sure what's the reason of your tests failing, but If it's with the integration, this should help.